# Trying to get all paths in a YAML file

Tags: yaml, pyyaml, ruamel.yaml

I've got an input YAML file (test.yml) as follows:

```
# sample set of lines
foo:
  x: 12
  y: hello world
  ip_range['initial']: 1.2.3.4
  ip_range[]: tba
  array['first']: Cluster1

array2[]: bar
```

The source contains square brackets for some keys (possibly empty).

I'm trying to get a line by line list of all the paths in the file, ideally like:

```
foo.x: 12
foo.y: hello world
foo.ip_range['initial']: 1.2.3.4
foo.ip_range[]: tba
foo.array['first']: Cluster1
array2[]: bar
```

I've used the [yamlpaths](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath) library and the `yaml-paths` CLI, but can't get the desired output. Trying this:

```
yaml-paths -m -s =foo -K test.yml
```

outputs:

```
foo.x
foo.y
foo.ip_range\[\'initial\'\]
foo.ip_range\[\]
foo.array\[\'first\'\]
```

Each path is on one line, but the output has all the escape characters ( \ ). Modifying the call to remove the -m option ("expand matching parent nodes") fixes that problem but the output is then not one path per line:

```
yaml-paths -s =foo -K test.yml
```

gives:

```
foo: {"x": 12, "y": "hello world", "ip_range['initial']": "1.2.3.4", "ip_range[]": "tba", "array['first']": "Cluster1"}
```

Any ideas how I can get the one line per path entry but without the escape chars? I was wondering if there is anything for path querying in the ruamel modules?

Comment: The recommended extension for YAML files, as per yaml.org,  has been `.yaml` since September 2006

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "paths" are nothing more than the joined string representation of the keys (and probably indices) of the
mappings (and potentially sequences) in your YAML document.

That can be trivially generated from data loaded from YAML with a recursive function:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
# sample set of lines
foo:
  x: 12
  y: hello world
  ip_range['initial']: 1.2.3.4
  ip_range[]: tba
  array['first']: Cluster1

array2[]: bar
"""

def pathify(d, p=None, paths=None, joinchar='.'):
    if p is None:
        paths = {}
        pathify(d, "", paths, joinchar=joinchar)
        return paths
    pn = p
    if p != "":
        pn += '.'
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            v = d[k]
            pathify(v, pn + k, paths, joinchar=joinchar)
    elif isinstance(d, list):
        for idx, e in enumerate(d):
            pathify(e, pn + str(idx), paths, joinchar=joinchar)
    else:
        paths[p] = d


yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML(typ='safe')
paths = pathify(yaml.load(yaml_str))

for p, v in paths.items():
    print(f'{p} -> {v}')
```

which gives:

```
foo.x -> 12
foo.y -> hello world
foo.ip_range['initial'] -> 1.2.3.4
foo.ip_range[] -> tba
foo.array['first'] -> Cluster1
array2[] -> bar
```

Answer (score 0):

While Anthon's answer certainly produces the output you were after, I think your question was specifically about how to get the `yaml-paths` command to produce the desired output.  I'll address *that* original question.

As of version 3.5.0, the [yamlpath](https://github.com/wwkimball/yamlpath) project's `yaml-paths` command supports a `--noescape` option which removes the escape symbols from output.    Using your input file and the new option, you may find this output more to your liking:

```
$ yaml-paths --nofile --expand --keynames --noescape --values --search='=~/.*/' test.yml
foo.x: 12
foo.y: hello world
foo.ip_range['initial']: 1.2.3.4
foo.ip_range[]: tba
foo.array['first']: Cluster1
array2[]: bar
```

Note:

1. Using the `--values` option includes the value with each YAML Path.
2. For interest, I changed the `--search` expression to match **every** node in the input file rather than only the "foo" data.
3. The default output (without setting `--noescape`) produces YAML Paths which can be used as direct input into other YAML Path parsers and processors; setting `--noescape` changes this to render human-friendly paths which may not work as downstream YAML Path input.

*Disclaimer*:  I am the author of the yamlpath project.  Should you ever run into issues or have questions about it, please visit the project's GitHub project site and engage me via Issues (bugs and feature requests) or Discussions (questions).  Thank you!